# How could I embed Lua into Python 3.x?

Tags: python, scripting, lua, python-3.x, embedding

Is it possible to embed Lua into Python 3.x?  If so how could I run and execute Lua scripts within my Python program?  How good would the interaction be between the Languages for instance would Lua have access to all of Python's variables and classes and would Python have access to all of Lua's information?

Comment: Why would you embed Lua in Python, which is a perfectly good scripting language and, of course, fully integrated with itself?

Comment: I was looking for a way to embed Lua into python to make a sort of fantasy computer. There are lot's of uses for embedding an interpreter inside of the existing one(Python).

Comment: Lua can be embedded in other programs written in other languages. Lua is tiny compared to Python, and so in many cases it makes sense to embed Lua and not Python. In this case it would be nice to be able to run the same scripts in both Python and in applications written in other languages. Python is too large to be embedded in general.

Answer (score 7):

Try [Lunatic Python](http://labix.org/lunatic-python), a two-way bridge between Python and Lua.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Lunatic Python, there is Lupa, powered by LuaJIT:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/lupa/0.9

See the link about advantages and reasons to use it.

Comment: As a side note: I do not agree with the "why use it" section there: it is not futile (or hard) to write large programs in Lua. I know, I have several hundred KLOC of Lua on my hands. The part about batteries is closer to truth though.

Comment: I both learned programming with Lua and have developed a disdain for it when trying to script a program that embeds it. Now I have to interpret *some* lua but will do my absolute best to touch it as little as possible.